# pandas operations over multiple axis

Tags: pandas

How can I do operations over multiple columns in one go in pandas?

For example, I would like to calculate the `df[['a',b']].mean(level=0)` or `df[['a',b']].kurtosis(level=0)` (I need the level=0 as it's a multi indexed dataframe).

But I would like to have one single number and do the calculation over multiple axis in one go. A and B would be merged into one single column (or series).

In numpy this is possible I believe with `axis=(0,1)`, but I'm unsure how this can be achieved in pandas.

Speed is very important, so apply or iterating is not a solution.

The expected result would be as follows:

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(10, 2),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('ab'), range(5)]),
    list('AB')
)
df
Out[76]: 
            A         B
a 0  0.444939  0.407554
  1  0.460148  0.465239
  2  0.462691  0.016545
  3  0.850445  0.817744
  4  0.777962  0.757983
b 0  0.934829  0.831104
  1  0.879891  0.926879
  2  0.721535  0.117642
  3  0.145906  0.199844
  4  0.437564  0.100702
```

expected result:

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(['mean']).mean(axis=1)
Out[78]: 
a    0.546125
b    0.529589
dtype: float64
```

But it needs to be achieved in one single calculation, not in mean of mean, as this will maybe work for the mean, but for other calculations it may not produce the same result as if it was done in one go (for example I'm not sure if the kurtosis of the kurtosis is equal to the kurtosis in one go.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sample dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(10, 2),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('ab'), range(5)]),
    list('AB')
)
df

            A         B
a 0  0.444939  0.407554
  1  0.460148  0.465239
  2  0.462691  0.016545
  3  0.850445  0.817744
  4  0.777962  0.757983
b 0  0.934829  0.831104
  1  0.879891  0.926879
  2  0.721535  0.117642
  3  0.145906  0.199844
  4  0.437564  0.100702
```

---

**Typical Solution**

Use `groupby` and `agg`

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(['mean', pd.Series.kurt])

          A                   B          
       mean      kurt      mean      kurt
a  0.599237 -2.885262  0.493013  0.018225
b  0.623945 -0.900488  0.435234 -3.105328
```

---

**Solve Different**

```
pd.concat([
    df.mean(level=0),
    df.kurt(level=0)
], axis=1, keys=['Mean', 'Kurt']).swaplevel(1, 0, 1).sort_index(1)

          A                   B          
       Kurt      Mean      Kurt      Mean
a -2.885262  0.599237  0.018225  0.493013
b -0.900488  0.623945 -3.105328  0.435234
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but I want A and B averaged into one single number in one go. So 0.599237 and  0.493013 would need to be merged into one single mean. Is it possible to do this one go. Also, any idea why calculating the kurtosis is so incredibly slow?

Comment: Can do that tomorrow when I’m on computer again. But it’s basically what you did but then the same operation again over the first axis, but everything should be done in one go.

Comment: What I'm looking for is `df.groupby(level=0).agg(['mean']).mean(axis=1)` but in one single go. Withouth having to take the mean of the mean.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```
df.stack().mean(level=0)

Out[146]: 
a    0.546125
b    0.529589
dtype: float64
```